# What does "where" refer to in this relative clause

Tags: relative-pronouns

This sentence is from **"Travel in Southeast Asia"**.

> Bangkok is the capital of Thailand and is regarded as a shopper's paradise. Some of its restaurants stage cultural
>   shows ***where*** one can enjoy the twin pleasures of Thai
>   cuisine and classical dance.

What does **where** refer in this sentence?

**1.** *at cultural shows*.

**2.** *at some of its restaurants*.

**3.** *at some of its restaurants  and cultural shows*.

I like #1 as **where** refers to the nearest place before it.

Comment: Without any doubt **where** is referring to *some restaurants where cultural shows were staged*. But I don't know what kind of grammatical structure this is. Dangling modifier? Not sure. But this sentence is fine as it is.

Comment: *Where* is a relative word, but not a pronoun.  Traditionally it would be a relative adverb, and in post-Jespersen grammar it's a relative preposition.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, *where* stands for *cultural shows*.

The structure: *One can enjoy the twin pleasures of Thai cuisine and classical dance **where***? In or  at *cultural shows staged by some of Thailand's restaurants.*

Note that  the count noun *restaurant* should be plural, so *some of its restaurants.*

Comment: Can we enjoy *cuisine* at cultural shows?

Comment: @learner I looked at the sentence grammatically; the author of the sentence is responsible for its logic.

Answer (score 0):

**Where** is a relative adverb beginning a relative clause. It refers to the word **shows**. During these shows you can enjoy the twin pleasures of Thai cuisine and classical dance.

Answer (score 0):

The word **where** is a very "loose" relative connector.   It need not refer to a place. It can refer back to an activity, a performance, an opportunity, a time-frame, almost anything really.